# No response form the server by pressing add button in android

Tags: android, json

Hi in the below code describes about the json request and json response from the server.We have button named as ADD.If you press on ADD button sending name and level as a request and based on the request want to get the status from server.

I'm unable to finding the error where i did the mistake .I am not getting any response from the server.

Add.java:

```
Add.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String name = et_building.getText().toString();
                final String level = "1";

                HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(API.URL_BASE)
                        .client(client)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                API service = retrofit.create(API.class);
                try{
                    JSONObject parmobject=new JSONObject ();
                    parmobject.put("name",name);
                    parmobject.put("level",level);
                    Call<NewBuilding> userCall = service.getbuildinglist (parmobject.toString ());
                    userCall.enqueue(new Callback<NewBuilding> () {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<NewBuilding> call, Response<NewBuilding> response) {


                            if (response != null && response.code ()==200) {

                                JSONObject obj = null;
                                try {
                                    obj = new JSONObject (String.valueOf (response));
                                    status=obj.getJSONObject (name).toString ();



                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON:");
                                }


                                if(status.equalsIgnoreCase ("success")){
                                    makeText(getActivity (), "Building successfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    arrayList.add (name);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();

                                }


                            } else {
                                makeText(getActivity (), "Please try again for Adding New Building", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<NewBuilding> call, Throwable t) {

                            t.printStackTrace ();

                        }
                    });
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

POJO classes:

NewBuilding.java:

```
public class NewBuilding {

    @SerializedName ("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Logcat error:

```
W/System.err: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1568)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1409)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:593)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:205)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:223)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: check if request works in postman. check if you pass the params and headers right. check if the response is successful.

Comment: @Raghunandan just because it works in Postman doesn't mean it will work in Android if you write incorrect code :)

Comment: @Zun agreed. i am looking at all possibilities that's all

Comment: It is working in postman

Comment: In LOgcat:POST http://xxxxxx/level/newbuilding http/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 36
D/OkHttp: "{\"name\":\"abc\",\"level\":\"1\"}"

Comment: Is the `onFailure` callback called? If so, what is the output in logcat?

Comment: NO.It is coming out of the loop

Comment: `out of the loop` which loop? There are no loops in your code.

Comment: not going inside response block'

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko please check it

Comment: the exception says that server responds with non-JSON

Comment: {
    "status": "success"
}

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko what is the solution

Comment: to check what does the server respond with and why. `{ "status": "success" } ` - error says that it is not what server responds with

Comment: {"nameValuePairs":{"name":"bujji","level":"1"}} after changed string to jsononject this is request

Comment: the problem is in the response, not request.

Comment: But same response i am using from another Api call it is working fine

Comment: then there is something different in this call. What is actual response here?

Comment: {
    "status": "success"
} response from postman

Comment: the problem is not in postman, you need to check actual response in Android

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko how to check it out actual response

Comment: try changing `Call<NewBuilding>` to `Call<String>`, so it returns result as string without attempting to parse it.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko status is not coming from server

Comment: then there is either a problem with server, or you are sending the request wrong way. Compare to what you are sending using postman. Or at least show the screenshot of postman here

Comment: move this discussion to chat?